# How to encrypt the response from get requests?

Tags: node.js, express

How do I encrypt the response from requests?
At the moment, if you go into the network, you can see the answer, there are all the data about the goods (price, category, etc.)
On the other side in this form (photo)

[image: photo]

Is it somehow parsed at the front and it turns out in a normal form?
Perhaps somehow you can, for example, just encrypt an object on the back, and decrypt it at the front?

Comment: Any decryption that's done in the frontend is just obfuscation at best, since the user is always in control of their browser, and can use e.g. the debugger in their developer console to break after the frontend has decrypted the data. If you don't want the user to be able to see some information, don't send it from the backend.

Comment: Going off the back of @AKX's comment, you should review some more foundational literature on how HTTPS operates in modern browsers, and specifically what protections it provides (hint: it certainly does not protect data from users themselves, especially those curious enough to be inspecting their own network traffic).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: JWE (JSON Web Encryption) is a thing: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516 but you should at least lay down authentication to the api to prevent scraping

Comment: I agree, but the customer requires that it is impossible to simply see all the data in the network. He wants encryption - like in the photo, or what it is (I'm not sure).

Comment: When a customer demands that the devtools Network tab not show anything useful, the customer shows their ignorance of how the web works. You could, potentially, obfuscate the data by, maybe, base64-encoding it. But a layer of encryption beyond tls (https) will be very difficult to secure. If an enduser should not see certain data, don't send it the their browser.

Comment: @O.Jones As an option, just encrypt every json and that's it? And give an array with encrypted json base64
Is it possible to somehow make it so that it can only be expanded with a key? or somehow come up with an algorithm, as in the photo

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes link photo

Answer (score 0):

The best and most practical thing to do is use HTTPS protocol so data can't be intercepted when sent from backend to frondend. No need for encyption.
You can also fiter the data in the backend, if you have sensitive infomation like passwords and emails, before sending to the frontend.

Comment: I agree, but the customer requires that it is impossible to simply see all the data in the network. He wants encryption - like in the photo, or what it is (I'm not sure).